# R code to align column length

Tags: r, alignment

I have a data.frame with columns of varying length that I'm trying to align according to the last value in each column. The first 5 rows contain specific identifying information that I can't discard.

I've been using a code in excel that does exactly what I want, but was hoping I could use a similar code to do the same process in R.

Sample data.frame (actual data set much larger):

> Series1 <- c("Lync", "23017323003", "2011", "sp1", "45.6", "2.4", "3.1", "1.9", "6.6", "1.4")
>   Series2 <- c("Lync", "23017323003", "2010", "sp2", "52.8", "3.8", "2.5", "4.3", "NA", "NA")
>   Series3 <- c("Faye", "23011195006", "2011", "sp1", "63.1", "1.3", "5.2", "0.7", "3.1", "NA")
>   df <- data.frame(Series1, Series2, Series3)

Intended output data.frame:

> Row_Names <- c("Town", "SiteID", "EndYear", "Subplot", "PathLength", "2007", "2008","2009", "2010", "2011")
>   Series1fix <- c("Lync", "23017323003", "2011", "sp1", "45.6", "2.4", "3.1", "1.9", "6.6", "1.4")
>   Series2fix <- c("Lync", "23017323003", "2010", "sp2", "52.8", "NA", "3.8", "2.5", "4.3", "NA")
>   Series3fix <- c("Faye", "23011195006", "2011", "sp1", "63.1", "NA", "1.3", "5.2", "0.7", "3.1")
>   FixedDF <- data.frame(Row_Names, Series1fix, Series2fix, Series3fix)

The excel code that someone helped me with is as follows:

```
Sub shift_to_last_row()

Dim LastRowOnSheet As Long
Dim LastRowInColumn As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Cells
LastRowOnSheet = .Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, False).Row
LastColumn = .Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False, False).Column
End With

For col = 1 To LastColumn
    LastRowInColumn = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRowInColumn <> LastRowOnSheet Then
    arr = Range(Cells(6, col), Cells(LastRowInColumn, col))
    Range(Cells(6, col), Cells(LastRowOnSheet, col)).ClearContents
    Range(Cells(6 + LastRowOnSheet - LastRowInColumn, col), Cells(LastRowOnSheet, col)) = arr
    End If
Next col
```

Any ideas on how to do this in R would be great. I have around 150 files to do this to, each containing around 50 columns and 150 rows.

**EDIT**
A sample subset of a real data.frame I'm using.

> structure(c("23017323003sp4", "2011", "40", "2/18/2014", "13:40:54", 
>   "67.9709", "2.516", "2.510", "1.095", "1.721", "0.574", "0.730", 
>   "0.924", "0.585", "1.565", "1.208", "1.104", "0.842", "0.671", 
>   "1.399", "1.136", "2.005", "0.946", "1.114", "1.191", "1.192", 
>   "2.217", "2.528", "3.706", "2.899", "2.646", "1.698", "1.815", 
>   "3.647", "2.141", "2.080", "1.022", "1.610", "2.25", "2.844", 
>   "2.651", "1.554", "1.538", "0.958", "1.290", "1.253", "23017323003sp4", 
>   "2011", "40", "2/18/2014", "13:40:54", "51.4189", "0.894", "0.977", 
>   "0.308", "0.670", "0.357", "0.151", "0.208", "0.256", "0.418", 
>   "0.591", "1.119", "0.758", "1.616", "1.698", "1.003", "1.774", 
>   "1.348", "1.088", "0.979", "0.992", "1.408", "1.312", "1.828", 
>   "1.429", "1.243", "1.093", "2.027", "2.205", "1.637", "1.456", 
>   "1.311", "1.531", "1.97", "2.182", "2.217", "2.128", "2.402", 
>   "1.471", "1.561", "1.449", "23017323003sp4", "2011", "19", "2/18/2014", 
>   "13:40:54", "36.6195", "1.631", "2.290", "1.652", "1.348", "1.335", 
>   "1.936", "3.442", "2.258", "1.883", "1.463", "1.282", "1.557", 
>   "2.282", "2.737", "2.736", "2.388", "1.346", "1.388", "1.240", 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(46L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("V2", 
>   "V3", "V9", "V13", "V14", "V112", "V113", "V114", "V115", "V116", 
>   "V117", "V118", "V119", "V120", "V121", "V122", "V123", "V124", 
>   "V125", "V126", "V127", "V128", "V129", "V130", "V131", "V132", 
>   "V133", "V134", "V135", "V136", "V137", "V138", "V139", "V140", 
>   "V141", "V142", "V143", "V144", "V145", "V146", "V147", "V148", 
>   "V149", "V150", "V151", "V152"), c("LY3A003B", "LY3A004A", "LY3A004B"
>   )))

**Using jlhoward's suggested code, I've tried the following (data.frame sample above is titled "Lync3rwlTrans":**

> series <- as.vector(Lync3rwlTrans[,3])
>   result <- do.call(cbind,lapply(series,function(s){
>   + data  <- s[7:46]
>   + data  <- data[data!="NA"]
>   + end   <- 40-(2011-as.numeric(s[2]))
>   + start <- end-length(data)+1
>   + ret <- rep("NA",40)
>   + ret[start:end] <- data
>   + return(c(s[1:6],ret))
>   + }))
>   rownames(result) <- c("SiteID", "EndYear", "#Rings", "EditDate", "EditTime", "PathLength", 1972:2011)
>   result <- data.frame(result, stringsAsFactors=F)
>   result

However, I keep getting the following error:
Error in start:end : NA/NaN argument

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand the *rule* of your *alignment*. When is a `NA` (or value) moved up?

Comment: The NAs are in there as fillers.... the original dataset has columns of varying lengths. The program that spits them out into a text file aligns them from the top, and I'm trying to align them from the bottom. So basically the last entry in every column should align according to the year entered in row 3. I've added an additional column on the left of the fixed dataset that hopefully explains how the columns are shifted (according to year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
series <- list(Series1,Series2,Series3)
result <- do.call(cbind,lapply(series,function(s){
  data  <- s[6:10]
  data  <- data[data!="NA"]
  end   <- 5-(2011-as.numeric(s[3]))
  start <- end-length(data)+1
  ret <- rep("NA",5)
  ret[start:end] <- data
  return(c(s[1:5],ret))
}))
rownames(result) <- c("Town", "SiteID", "EndYear", "Subplot", "PathLength", "2007", "2008","2009", "2010", "2011")
result <- data.frame(result, stringsAsFactors=F)
result
#                     X1          X2          X3
# Town              Lync        Lync        Faye
# SiteID     23017323003 23017323003 23011195006
# EndYear           2011        2010        2011
# Subplot            sp1         sp2         sp1
# PathLength        45.6        52.8        63.1
# 2007               2.4          NA          NA
# 2008               3.1         3.8         1.3
# 2009               1.9         2.5         5.2
# 2010               6.6         4.3         0.7
# 2011               1.4          NA         3.1
```

Note the following:

1. I combined the `Series<n>` into a list because that would be the best way to import the files.
2. In your example, everything ends up type `char`, so that's the way this code works as well.
3. Your NA's are also char, e.g. `"NA"`, not `NA`. So tests like `is.na(...)` will not work.

**EDIT** (Response to OP's followup question)

So there are two problems. First, there is a difference between `"NA"` and `NA`. The first is a character string, which you test for using, e.g., `data=="NA"`. The second is the R value `NA` which you test for using, e.g. `is.na(data)`. *I explained this in my notes above.* In your "sample data", you had `"NA"`, which I accommodated in code. In your "real data", you have `NA`, so the code does not work. This is why you get the error. Replace

```
data <- data[data!="NA"]
```

with

```
data <- data[!is.na(data)]
```

Second, if your "real data" is in a character matrix `Lync3rwlTrans`, use

```
df <- data.frame(Lync3rwlTrans,stringsAsFactors=F)
result <- do.call(cbind,lapply(df, function(s)...)
```

This will convert `Lync3rwlTrans` to a data frame and pass that column-wise to the re-alignment function.

The full code is:

```
df <- data.frame(Lync3rwlTrans,stringsAsFactors=F)
result <- do.call(cbind,lapply(df,function(s){
  data  <- s[7:46]
  data  <- data[!is.na(data)]
  end   <- 40-(2011-as.numeric(s[2]))
  start <- end-length(data)+1
  ret <- rep(NA,40)
  ret[start:end] <- data
  return(c(s[1:6],ret))
}))
rownames(result) <- c("SiteID", "EndYear", "#Rings", "EditDate", "EditTime", "PathLength", 1972:2011)
result <- data.frame(result, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Finally, *this would have been SO much easier if you had revealed your "real data" at the beginning!!*

Comment: This is a great solution! Thanks for the assistance altering the code!    Just one quick question: I'd like to run the code in batch, and each data.frame has a different number of columns and rows. Is there a simple way to run "> series <- list(x1, x2, x3)"  for all columns, without specifying column names? Such as 1:n? The same would apply for rows; is there a way to use "> end   <- 5-(2011-as.numeric(s[3]))" multiple times if the number of rows (5 in this case) constantly changes between data.frames?

Comment: I'd need to see an example.

Comment: I just edited my original question with a small subset of real data, along with a version of the code you provided that I've been attempting to use.

Comment: Thank you for the recent edit. I'm sorry for not putting the real data in to start with; being new to R I just learned how to extract the code for a dataset a few days ago.  The edited code works perfectly, and I appreciate your patience.